# Arabic font in Phaser.js

Tags: phaser-framework

Hi I wanted to add some Arabic text to my Phaser game. I have the following in the update() function:

```
    this.scoreText = this.add.text( this.world.centerX, this.world.height/5, 
                         "",{nsize: "32px", fill: "#FFF", align: "center"});

    this.scoreText.setText("تُفاحة");
```

This produces strange letters on the screen which are not Arabic. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, you shouldn't be *adding* text in the `update()` method - this would cause it to be added multiple times (once for each frame, ideally 60 times per second). Move it to the `create()` method so that it's only added once. You also have a typo in the parameters: `nsize` should be just `size`.

```
function create() {
    this.scoreText = this.add.text( this.world.centerX, this.world.height / 5, "", { size: "32px", fill: "#FFF", align: "center" });
    this.scoreText.setText("تُفاحة");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like

Import the font in the CSS part in index.html

```
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/earlyaccess/amiri.css);
```

Then just declare the style as a variable

```
var style = { font: "32px Amiri", fill: "#333", align: "center" };
```

Then in the create function add the text like in this jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/albator2018/r2zLtoqd/

There is another manner to do it but like what i've just explained it works fine